# How do I evaluate an expression after running script in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I run a long script that creates a list.  But afterwards I want to check how many items are in the list.  Currently, I put len(list1) at the bottom of the script, re-run, and see the output.

But, what if it's a long script and I don't want to re-run the whole script again?  Is there a way to evaluate only len(list1) without running from the beginning?  I looked into debug mode but even debug mode would re-running the script in it's entirety wouldn't it?

Comment: "Is there a way to evaluate only len(list1) without running from the beginning?" Not sure how you expect that to work. You could serialize your results and inspect them again without running the whole script

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with pycharm as far as I can tell

Comment: No, once you execute a script and it terminates, it's not accessible anymore.

Comment: Open a file and store the result there

Comment: If you have a long script that does a lot of work and you want to try multiple options from the intermediate state, you need to find some way to save the state, like writing it to a file and reloading the state from there later, to avoid having to redo all the computation. If you provide a more concrete example, it would be easier to provide some guidance.

Comment: if you want run again only  `len(list1)` then you should get exactly the same result as before - so it make no sense.